# What is the best way to copy a list of lists of strings in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm new to Python, and to copy a matrix to another, I'm doing:

```
import copy
matrix1.append(copy.deepcopy(matrix2))
```

Is there a better, maybe a shorter, way?

**--update:**

The types are lists of strings, like `[["asdf", "fdsa"], ["zxcv", "vcxz"]]`, and I want to add this to my other list, but I don't want them to be the same reference (I want to edit one without change the other).

Comment: You need to explain to us what types these are.

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do. Do you want to add the content of the second matrix to the first one ?

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: I updated the question, please, take a look.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, I want to append a copy of the content.

Comment: given your needs, there is no shorter way. You can do a `from copy import deepcopy; matrix1.append(deepcopy(matrix2))` if you prefer...

Answer (score 2):

1. *Are you sure you need to copy anything?* The strong majority of the time, it's best not to copy data like this. Doing so implies you're going to mutate the copy. Very often it's possible just to make a new thing rather than to mutate a copy, which ends up being less errorprone as your program develops. What were you planning to do with the copy, and are you sure it isn't better done while creating the new thing rather than after?
2. *If I were to copy* `x = [["asdf", "fdsa"], ["zxcv", "vcxz"]]`, I would write `copy = [list(ss) for ss in x]` (or `map(list, x)`). This makes it pretty clear exactly what I'm doing.
3. *I avoid the `copy` module* when I do need to copy data. Because of the way it works, the copy module can fail or give wrong answers. It mostly promises to be useful when you don't know the structure or content of the stuff you're copying, but if you don't know that, you usually have a more fundamental problem than "how do I copy it?", namely, "how do I use it?"

Comment: Looks like `[list(ss) for ss in matrix2]` works just like `copy.deepcopy(matrix2)`, I just don't understand what's the difference between using `list(ss)` or just `ss`, isn't `ss` a list already?

Comment: @Tom, `list` makes a new list containing the same items as the old one. For all intents and purposes, list is defined like `def list(iterable): return [item for item in iterable]`.

Comment: can you give an example of when the copy module can fail or give wrong answers please?

Comment: @Andrew, Consider `def f(): pass` `f.n = 4` `g = copy.copy(f)` `g.n = 16` `print f.n` or a user-defined object that has a numeric file descriptor it needs to manage/close.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is actually a list, then this is simpler:

```
import copy
matrix1 = copy.deepcopy(matrix2)
```

Your code is extending `matrix1`, which would have to exist beforehand, and why are you preserving its original contents in addition to adding the new stuff?

UPDATE:

Yes, what you have is the best way.

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry for not explaining better, I really mean I want to append, and it's to an existing matrix.

Comment: @Tom, I don't fully follow you. You have something like `x = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]` and `y = [['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]` and you want to turn `x` into `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]`, and additionally you want to do `y[0][0] = 'q'` later and not change anything contained in `x`?

Comment: @Mike Graham: yes, perfectly this.

Comment: @Tom, `x.extend(list(strings) for strings in y)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
original = [[1,2],[3,4]]
copy = [i[:] for i in original]
```

Does it have more than 2 dimensions? Otherwise stay with deepcopy

if you want to append:

```
matrix1.append([i[:] for i in original])
```